# Iphone webapp keep alive

Tags: iphone, ajax, gps, iphone-web-app

I am currently developing a web app application for iphone

The main fonctionnality of this app is to collect GPS data in a regular way ( every 10 sec ) 
in order to be sent via AJAX to a WebService and saved...

the problem is that after a few moments , the iphone goes in sleep mode ( screen switch off ) and then the process is no longer active

is there a way to keep the application constantly awake like some traditional applications such as  GPS applications ?

Comment: Curious how long battery could live under such load.

Comment: is it a pure web app? or are you then using some wrapper like PhoneGap?

Comment: it's a pure web app , no wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not keep a device awake with a non-native app. [See the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).